# Is there any way to to get data from Dev2Dev to Grafana?

Tags: c#, in-app-purchase, grafana, google-play-developer-api

I'm looking for solution how to show revenue data in Grafana dashboard without refactoring client side.

I have purchase validation (ios and android) on my server, but don't have any info about purchase price or region of purchase, just the item name...

But client sends metrics to Dev2Dev service. May be is there any way to get this metric from Dev2Dev, or may be is there any api to get the purchasing price on server side from apple and google play?

Answer (score 0):

Google Play has [a developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/#subscriptions) for in app purchase information.

You can also [download sales reports](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2482017)